# A recent Chrome update broke button layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Just today, whatever Google changed in Chrome caused it to incorrectly display a sequence of buttons that are floated to the right.

Note: the content of the page is loaded dynamically via AJAX.

Before:

[image]

Today:

[image]

Here's where it gets strange. These buttons are contained in a `div` that only has `float: right;` applied to it (the buttons are `display:inline-block`). I tried changing the `div` to a `span` *in the inspector*. That fixed the problem, so I tried replacing the `div` with a `span` in my code. However, the problem remained when I refreshed the page. I went into the inspector, and changed the container back to a `div`, and that fixed the problem again. However, obviously, changing it back to a `div` in my actual code and refreshing the page caused the problem to come back.

Only changing the container from a `div` to a `span` or from a `span` to a `div` **in the inspector** fixes the issue.

Also, when the page first loads, it seems like the buttons are in the correct position for a brief flicker of a second before they are messed up.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug in the newest Chrome build (I'm using Version 31.0.1650.57 m) or otherwise. I'm not sure what the best way to fix this is.

This issue is not present in Firefox or IE, just Chrome, and not before today.

Some relevant HTML:

```
<div class='right'>
  <div class='button'>Button ...</div>
  <div class='button'>Turn Away</div>
  <div class='button'>More button! ...</div>
  <div class='button'>About</div>
  <div class='button'>Logout</div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/83cLt/ (note: I am not able to reproduce the error on JSFiddle even by copying all of my HTML and CSS)

**UPDATE**

I found the source of the problem. The buttons with "..." were buttons that had an associated dropdown menu created dynamically. This dropdown menu was in the form of a div added after the button (button, div.dropdown, button, div.dropdown, button, button). This `div` was hiding by having a `max-height` of `0`. For some reason, in Chrome, if elements are added dynamically that have a height of 0 (even if they are `inline-block`), they now do not load properly. To fix the issue, I added a `display:none` to the `div.dropdown` and change that back and forth when the dropdown is showing or not.

Comment: I added in some relevant code, but the gist of it was already described in the question.

Comment: Yes, but that's a slow and non-mobile way to present your code. Thank you.

Comment: Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/83cLt/

Comment: try 'white-space: nowrap;' once.

Comment: Does the problem appear for you in the fiddle? I'm in the same version and it does not.

Comment: The problem is not present in the fiddle for me, no. I'll see if I can put enough code in to recreate the issue. I had hoped someone ran into something similar or knew what Chrome might have changed.

Comment: The same issue occurs on older IE, where floated elements don't expand, but not Chrome.

Comment: I tried just copy/pasting the HTML and CSS directly from the page into JSFiddle, but it works in JSFiddle, presumably similarly to how it works after arbitrarily changing the `div` to a `span` or the `span` to a `div`.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a place where we CAN see it reproduced?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is for a web tool ran on a local network.

Comment: This happens on everyone's computer and not just yours?

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it in http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Yes, it happens on everyone's computer. I've had reports of it from all machines. I tried reproducing it on codepen and jsbin; no dice. I think the reason why is because it seems to be a bug that happens when the content is loaded dynamically via AJAX. Changing `div` to `span` and vice versa seems to reset the rendering to be correct.

Comment: Well you can add the dynamic update to the example using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Even if that fixed the problem, it would be a pretty awful fix. I tried it anyhow out of curiosity and it did not fix the issue regardless.

Comment: No, I mean can you use `setTimeout` to try to reproduce the problem in jsFiddle or jsBin?

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately, it didn't reproduce the error.

Comment: Can you show the code that dynamically updates the buttons?

Comment: The buttons aren't dynamically updated. The entire page is loaded via AJAX (it's a Backbone.js app) at once.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to comment out the whitespace between your divs.

```
<div class='right'>
  <div class='button'>Button ...</div><!--
  --><div class='button'>Turn Away</div><!--
  --><div class='button'>More button! ...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that might work for you. Instead of using `float`, use `position`.

```
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/83cLt/1/

Note that the parent element has to have `position: relative;`.

Comment: Sorry. I remember running into a similar issue a while back, but now I can't remember how I solved it. :-(

Comment: Thanks anyhow; maybe I'll figure out how to circumvent this eventually. I filed a bug report for Chrome. Hopefully they'll get around to fixing it. Eventually. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see this happening is if something else in the code is pushing the div block over, either by a default styling or a mobile screen width setting or something floated left. If you post more of the code, it can probably be pinpointed, but for a quick fix, I would add

```
    .right {
        float: right;
        min-width: 340px;
    }
```

or whatever width you need.

Comment: @CezaryWojcik - What happens if you remove the ellipses from the buttons? That seems to be where the line breaks are happening.

Comment: This wasn't directly the problem, but it helped me figure out what exactly was causing the issue in Chrome. OP is updated for details. Thanks!

Comment: Even with a height of 0, `display:block` (whether default or specified) is still block.  

And no offense, but this is the biggest reason that everyone asks to see the actual html and css. The fact that the ellipses were dropdowns was not apparent from the code that was posted. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: For clarification, this had nothing to do with the fact that the `div.dropdown` had its default `display:block`. When the rendering was reset by changing the `div` to a `span` or vice versa, it is rendered correctly. It was the fact that those elements of `max-height:0` were being added dynamically that was messed up in this build of Chrome. When the element doesn't have height, it should be treated similarly to `display:none`, which does happen if the code is loaded statically.

Comment: Ahh. I get it. So only because it was rendered dynamically. I wonder if it has anything to do with chrome's anonymous nested block creation. Seem to recall a bug or 2 relating to that.